# Got an extra box below listing

Tags: listings

When I tried to import *main.cpp* inside the latex file, I always get an **extra block** which is below the Listing.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%Defint the color
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{cppStyle}{ %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    morekeywords={string,Node, Node*},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\tiny,                
    basicstyle=\ttfamily ,       
    numbers=left,                   
    numberstyle=\ttfamily ,    
    stepnumber=5,                   
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,               
    showstringspaces=false,        
    showtabs=false,               
    frame=single,         
    tabsize=2,     
    captionpos=b,  
    breaklines=false, 
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
}

\lstset{style=cppStyle}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \lstinputlisting[nolol=true]{main.cpp}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={C++ Hello World}, label={lst:cpp_hello_world}]
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result for the latex file]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have two listings, one of which is empty. The caption and label should be passed as options to `\lstinputlisting`.

Comment: @egreg OMG! Thank you for your help ! It did solve my problem, and I think I need a cup of coffee.

Comment: Well, it's lunch time for me. `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

You have two listings, one of which is empty. The caption and label should be passed to the `\lstinputlisting` command.

I take the occasion to suggest some improvements.

1. the `minipage` is useless (and makes harm, because it adds the paragraph indentation)
2. the `style` can be passed as option
3. the `style` should be defined in the preamble

Here's a full example, the `filecontents*` environment is just to make it self-contained (and not clobber my files).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.cpp}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout<<"Hello World in C++"<<endl;

  return 0;

}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%Defint the color
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\lstdefinestyle{cppStyle}{
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    morekeywords={string,Node, Node*},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\tiny,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily,
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    frame=single,
    tabsize=2,
    captionpos=b,
    breaklines=false,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[
  style=cppStyle,
  nolol=true,
  caption={C++ Hello World},
  label={lst:cpp_hello_world}
]{\jobname.cpp}

\end{document}
```

[image]